# socket.io client can't connect/reconnect reliably

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am utilizing socket.io V3.1.1 and am trying to figure out how to get the client to reconnect after the connection is disconnected due to a phone going asleep.  When I run the code, it connects, refreshes an order, and then I press the power button on the iPhone to cause it to sleep.  I then press the home key, and I see a disconnect event, followed by a connect event which refreshes the order.  If I repeat the process, I see it disconnect, but I never see a connect event.

The question is, how does one reliably connect/reconnect and/or why don't I get additional connect events?

Here's a sample console.log output:

```
connect
refreshOrder 1234
disconnect due to transport error
connect
refreshOrder 1234
disconnect due to transport error

and then no more events
```

Here's the primary code that's involved:

```
    const socket = io("wss://xyz.org:3000");

    socket.on('connect', () => {
        console.log("connect");
        if (order_id !== null){
            refreshOrder(order_id);
        }
    });
    
    socket.on("disconnect", (reason) => {
        console.log("disconnect due to " + reason);
        socket.connect();
    });
```

I also have the following event handlers, but they never get called:

```
    socket.on('reconnect', () => {
        console.log('reconnect');
        if (order_id !== null){
            refreshOrder(order_id);
        }
    });

    socket.on("connect_error", (err) => {
        console.log("connect_error: " + err);
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("socket.connect retry");
            socket.connect();
        }, 1000);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that you should ignore the disconnect and let the built-in reconnect code handle it.  I believe that my problem was that I had looked at examples of pre-V3 code and didn't understand that it was handled differently in V3.  So, a better disconnect event handler would be

```
    socket.on("disconnect", (reason) => {
        console_log("disconnect due to " + reason);
        if (reason === "io server disconnect") {  
            // disconnect initiated by server. Manually reconnect
            socket.connect();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Just letting socket.io handle reconnections without manually reconnecting in any event handler worked.